# Failed to bounce to type?

Tags: android, firebase

O erro ocorre quando adiciono o atributo do tipo long, com o tipo String não dá erro,consigo inserir no banco mas dá erro no `getvalue`.

**Segue o código**

```
package com.mycompany.parcelasdecartao;

import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;
import com.firebase.client.*;
import com.mycompany.parcelasdecartao.model.*;
import java.util.*;

public class CadastrarParcelaActivity extends Activity 
{

    private EditText editTextNumParcelas;
    private EditText editTextDescricao;
    private EditText editTextValor;
    private EditText editTextDataCompra;
    private Button buttonSave;

    //CRIA POPUP COM O CALENDÁRIO
    DatePickerDialog datePickerDialogDataNascimento;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cadastrar_parcela);

        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);

        /*CARREGA O MÉTODO DE CRIAÇÃO DOS COMPONENTES*/
        this.CriarComponentes();

        this.CriarEventos();

    }


    //VINCULA O COMPONENTE DA NOSSA TELA AO OBJETO DA NOSSA ATIVIDADE
    protected void CriarComponentes(){

        //VINCULANDO A LISTA DA TELA AO LISTVIEW QUE DECLARAMOS

        buttonSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSave);

        editTextNumParcelas = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextNumParcelas);
        editTextValor = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextValCompra);
        editTextDataCompra = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextDatCompra);
        editTextDescricao = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextDescCompra);

    }

    //CRIA EVENTO PARA A LISTA
    protected void CriarEventos(){

        final Calendar calendarDataAtual = Calendar.getInstance();
        int anoAtual   = calendarDataAtual.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int mesAtual   = calendarDataAtual.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int diaAtual   = calendarDataAtual.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        //MONTANDO O OBJETO DE DATA PARA PREENCHER O CAMPOS QUANDO  FOR SELECIONADO
        //FORMATO DD/MM/YYYY
        datePickerDialogDataNascimento = new DatePickerDialog(this,new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int anoSelecionado, int mesSelecionado, int diaSelecionado) {

                    //FORMATANDO O MÊS COM DOIS DÍGITOS
                    String mes = (String.valueOf((mesSelecionado + 1)).length() == 1 ? "0" + (mesSelecionado + 1 ): String.valueOf(mesSelecionado));

                    editTextDataCompra.setText(diaSelecionado + "/" + mes + "/" + anoSelecionado);

                }

            }, anoAtual, mesAtual, diaAtual);



        //CRIANDO EVENTO NO CAMPO DE DATA PARA ABRIR A POPUP
        editTextDataCompra.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    datePickerDialogDataNascimento.show();
                }
            });


        //CRIANDO EVENTO NO CAMPO DE DATA PARA ABRIR A POPUP
        editTextDataCompra.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

                    datePickerDialogDataNascimento.show();

                }
            });





        buttonSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View p1)
                {
                    // TODO: Implement this method
                    String parcelaId;
                    String caminho = "/Compras";
                    //Creating firebase object
                    Firebase ref = new Firebase(Config.FIREBASE_URL + caminho);

                    //desabiltando o botao pata evitsr dula entras
                    buttonSave.setEnabled(false);

                    //novo objeto parcelas

                    ParcelaCartao parcela = new ParcelaCartao();

                    long num_parcelas = Long.parseLong(editTextNumParcelas.getText().toString());

                        parcela.setNumparcelas(num_parcelas);
                        parcela.setDescricao(editTextDescricao.getText().toString().trim());

                        parcelaId = ref.push().getKey();

                        ref.child(parcelaId).setValue(parcela);

                        ref.child(parcelaId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                                //habilitando o botao pata evitsr dula entras
                                buttonSave.setEnabled(true);

                                ParcelaCartao parcela = new ParcelaCartao();
                                ArrayList<ParcelaCartao> array = new ArrayList<>();
                                for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren())
                                {

                                    parcela = childSnapshot.getValue(ParcelaCartao.class);
                                    array.add(parcela);
                                }                   



                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                                System.out.println("The read failed: " + firebaseError.getMessage());
                            }

                        }); }
            }); }

}
```

**Segue o Json**

```
{
  "-KvlDeyP0v8O76tUnuKW" : {
    "descricao" : "teste com long",
    "numparcelas" : 5
  },
  "-KvmwSsqnPir51cPi6NJ" : {
    "descricao" : "teste tarde",
    "numparcelas" : 5
  },
  "-KvrFqmHHzD0SkOguotR" : {
    "descricao" : "teste sabado",
    "numparcelas" : 6
  }
}
```

**Segue a classe**

```
import com.google.firebase.database.*;
/**
 * Created by Belal on 2/23/2016.
 */

@IgnoreExtraProperties
public class ParcelaCartao
{

    private String descricao;
    private long numparcelas;

    public ParcelaCartao(String descricao, long numparcelas ){
        setDescricao(descricao);
        setNumparcelas(numparcelas);


        }


    public ParcelaCartao() {
        /*Blank default constructor essential for Firebase*/
    }



    public String getDescricao()
    {
        return descricao;
    }

    public void setDescricao(String descricao)
    {
        this.descricao = descricao;
    }

    public Long getNumparcelas()
    {
        return numparcelas;
    }

    public void setNumparcelas(long numparcelas)
    {
        this.numparcelas = numparcelas;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Compra: " +  descricao +
            "\n num_parcelas: " + numparcelas;

    }   
    }
```

**Segue o erro**

> 07 11:45:09.745 21664 21664 E  
>   AndroidRuntime                               FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   10-07 11:45:09.745 21664 21664 E  
>   AndroidRuntime                               Process:
>   com.mycompany.parcelasdecartao, PID: 21664 10-07 11:45:09.745 21664
>   21664 E   AndroidRuntime                              
>   com.firebase.client.FirebaseException: Failed to bounce to type 10-07
>   11:45:09.745 21664 21664 E  
>   AndroidRuntime                               at
>   com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot.getValue(DataSnapshot.java:185) 10-07
>   11:45:09.745 21664 21664 E  
>   AndroidRuntime                               at
>   com.mycompany.parcelasdecartao.CadastrarParcelaActivity$100000004$100000003$0$debug.onDataChange(CadastrarParcelaActivity.java:169)
>   10-07 11:45:09.745 21664 21664 E  
>   AndroidRuntime                               at
>   com.mycompany.parcelasdecartao.CadastrarParcelaActivity$100000004$100000003.onDataChange(CadastrarParcelaActivity.java)
>   10-07 11:45:09.745 21664 21664 E  
>   AndroidRuntime                               at
>   com.firebase.client.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(ValueEventRegistration.java:45)
>   10-07 11:45:09.745 21664 21664 E  
>   AndroidRuntime                               at
>   com.firebase.client.core.view.DataEvent.fire(DataEvent.java:45) 10-07
>   11:45:09.745 21664 21664 E  
>   AndroidRuntime                               at
>   com.firebase.client.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(EventRaiser.java:38)
>   10-07 11:45:09.745 21664 21664 E  
>   AndroidRuntime                               at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746) 10-07 11:45:09.745
>   21664 21664 E   AndroidRuntime                               at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 10-07 11:45:09.745
>   21664 21664 E   AndroidRuntime                               at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 10-07 11:45:09.745 21664 21664
>   E   AndroidRuntime                               at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443) 10-07
>   11:45:09.745 21664 21664 E  
>   AndroidRuntime                               at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 10-07 11:45:09.745
>   21664 21664 E   AndroidRuntime                               at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
>   10-07 11:45:09.745 21664 21664 E  
>   AndroidRuntime                               at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618) 10-07
>   11:45:09.745 21664 21664 E  
>   AndroidRuntime                               Caused by:
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not
>   instantiate value of type [simple type, class
>   com.mycompany.parcelasdecartao.model.ParcelaCartao] from String value;
>   no single-String constructor/factory method 10-07 11:45:09.745 21664
>   21664 E   AndroidRuntime                               at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdValueInstantiator._createFromStringFallbacks(StdValueInstantiator.java:428)
>   10-07 11:45:09.745 21664 21664 E  
>   AndroidRuntime                               at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdValueInstantiator.createFromString(StdValueInstantiator.java:299)
>   10-07 11:45:09.745 21664 21664 E  
>   AndroidRuntime                               at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromString(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1056)
>   10-07 11:45:09.745 21664 21664 E  
>   AndroidRuntime                               at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeOther(BeanDeserializer.java:136)
>   10-07 11:45:09.745 21664 21664 E  
>   AndroidRuntime                               at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:123)
>   10-07 11:45:09.745 21664 21664 E  
>   AndroidRuntime                               at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2888)
>   10-07 11:45:09.745 21664 21664 E  
>   AndroidRuntime                               at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2034)
>   10-07 11:45:09.745 21664 21664 E  
>   AndroidRuntime                               at
>   com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot.getValue(DataSnapshot.java:183) 10-07
>   11:45:09.745 21664 21664 E  
>   AndroidRuntime                               ... 12 more

Imagem do banco:
[image]

Comment: Aqui funcionou normalmente. Tem certeza que seu banco está exatamente assim?

Comment: Olá Pablo, obrigado por me ajudar. Inseri o código completo, quem sabe você encontra o erro . Sobre o  banco de dados postei uma imagem da console do firebase.

Comment: Utilizo o AIDE como ferramenta para desenvolvimento. Será que ficou lixo em algum lugar que está gerando este erro? Estou pensando em só usar string ou reescrever o projeto do zero. Obrigado.